# HTML5-canvas make circles blink inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've drawn few small circles(filled with red color) inside a canvas as a markup, and now i want them to blink on which i'm failing to succeed. Please anyone help, I'm stuck.

```
var X = 135;
var Y = 70;

function button() {
    var butt = c.getContext("2d");
    butt.beginPath();
    butt.arc(X, Y, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    butt.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    butt.fill();
    butt.stroke();
    butt.css('visibility', butt.css('visibility') === 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden')
}
button();
button(X = 200, Y = 100);
button(X = 280, Y = 200);
```

Comment: show what you have tried ?

Comment: var X = 135;
        var Y = 70;
        function button() {
            var butt = c.getContext("2d");
            butt.beginPath();
            butt.arc(X, Y, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            butt.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            butt.fill();
            butt.stroke();
            butt.css('visibility', butt.css('visibility') === 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden')
        }

        button();
        button(X = 200, Y = 100);
        button(X = 280, Y = 200);

Comment: sorry, i just dont know how to add my program on here, im a beginner here ...

Comment: The negative vote is so unfair. At least give the guy some warm welcome. He is new to the community and there is no reason supplied for the negative vote...

Comment: you can make a fiddle click  --> http://jsfiddle.net/ and paste all you code and edit your question and post the link of fiddle after saving .

Comment: @NaveedButt I completely agree: [we shouldn't be hostile toward new Stack Overflow users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

Comment: @user2699096: You can just paste your program into the question. For formatting inline code wrap it within the ` symbol. For multi-line code, do (a) indent by 4 spaces or (b) select the entire code and press Ctrl + K or (c) select the entire code and click the `{}` button present in the button bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to make two changes to your function. Pass in parameters and return a reference to the button.

```
function button(X, Y) {
    var butt = c.getContext("2d");
    butt.beginPath();
    butt.arc(X, Y, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    butt.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    butt.fill();
    butt.stroke()
}
```

This allows you to create the buttons like this and keep a reference :

```
b1 = button(135, 70);
b2 = button(200, 100);
b3 = button(280, 200);
```

You can then create a function that toggles visibility and call it like

```
function toggle_button(items){
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.css('visibility', item.css('visibility') === 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
    });
    setTimeout(function toggle_buttons(items),500);
}

setTimeout(function toggle_buttons([b1, b2, b3]),500);
```

In order to blink, the function toggle_buttons must set a timeout itself to keep the blinking going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys esp. @Naveed thats real motivating. and how do i make them blink i need them to blink 'the visibility hidden is not working for me .

Comment: @Aditya Of course the line `butt.css('visibility', butt.css('visibility') === 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden')`has to go into the toggle function. I edit my answer.

Comment: @Aditya if this answer solved your problem, use the tick on the left hand side to accept it. It prevents others coming here to help solve a problem that's already been solved. Welcome to SO - hope to see you around

Comment: DO I need an extra animation supporting canvas for my object to blink?

Comment: @Aditya Sorry, but I don't understand your question. I did not test my code, but it should be complete.

Comment: sorry @LorenzMeyer its not working, can u test ur code and solve it when ur free ofcourse.

Comment: @Aditya No, it comes as it is with no warranty whatsoever :) I hope it helps you to get the idea how to do it.

Comment: Yeah that code is incomplete and it will not going to work because the context has no attribute css. There is no css support because its a drawing engine... Can't understand the 4 upvotes then...